# Accelerometer and Gyroscope as inputs for LSTM TFLite model on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, lstm, tensorflow-lite, android-sensors, bytebuffer

I'm trying to create an application which takes in the smartphone sensor data (accelerometer and gyroscope) that predicts the driving style currently produced (eg. Right turn, Left turn ,etc). I've already converted the LSTM model into TFLite model and have imported it into Android Studio and the sample code below was created . What I understand is we need to create a **byteBuffer** to load the input into the model. Here is the sample code after I have imported it into the project:

```
try {
    FullDataDriverprofiler model = FullDataDriverprofiler.newInstance(context);

    // Creates inputs for reference.
    TensorBuffer inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[]{1, 50, 6}, DataType.FLOAT32);
    inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer);

    // Runs model inference and gets result.
    FullDataDriverprofiler.Outputs outputs = model.process(inputFeature0);
    TensorBuffer outputFeature0 = outputs.getOutputFeature0AsTensorBuffer();

    // Releases model resources if no longer used.
    model.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Handle the exception
}
```

I have initialized the sensors, and have stored them inside an ArrayList (I've stored the accelerometer and gyroscope data into an ArrayList where each axis takes in 50 values at a time):

```
 private void predictActivities() {

        //create new list to combine all arrayLists into one big list. Data will be our input variable
        List<Float> data = new ArrayList<>();
        if( ax.size() >= TIME_STAMP && ay.size() >= TIME_STAMP && az.size() >= TIME_STAMP
         && gx.size() >= TIME_STAMP && gy.size() >= TIME_STAMP && gz.size() >= TIME_STAMP)
        {
            data.addAll(ax.subList(0, TIME_STAMP));
            data.addAll(ay.subList(0, TIME_STAMP));
            data.addAll(az.subList(0, TIME_STAMP));

            data.addAll(gx.subList(0, TIME_STAMP));
            data.addAll(gy.subList(0, TIME_STAMP));
            data.addAll(gz.subList(0, TIME_STAMP));
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "predictActivities: Data in List ArrayList"+ data);
```

I then convert the ArrayList into a Float array:

```
private float[] toFloatArray(List<Float> data){
        int i = 0;
        float[] array = new float[data.size()];
        for (Float f: data){
            array[i++] = (f !=null ? f: Float.NaN);
        }
        return array;
    }
```

How do we feed the float array as input for the TFlite model? I've seen examples where they use TensorImage() to pass in the inputs but that is solely for images right? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Instead of using a `TensorImage` use a `TensorBuffer` from the TFLite Support library.

Comment: do you have any references that I can follow? This is all brand new to me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @EilhamHakimie How did you solve it? I am looking to solve a similar problem